# Android Return Line (\n) in String

Tags: android, string, android-edittext, newline, textview

In android, a String resource can be created in XML by using

```
<string name="name">data</string>
```

to create a new line, `\n` may be used. However, if the user personally inputs data into an EditText and includes a `\n`, the writing is saved to a `String` and when the writing is displayed again in a TextView the result would be something such as:

```
Line 1\nLine2
```

How come the `\n` doesn't apply to user written Strings?

The end goal for me is to be able to have the user type a `\n` into a String to make sure the `String` is displayed in multiple lines.

How would this be achieved? Thanks in advance!

Comment: try to set  android:maxLines="4" in textView layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this :

```
TextView view = your text view;
view.setSingleLine(false);

view.setText("first line" + "\n" + "second line" + "\n" + "third line");
```

Comment: What would be the best way to split the string at the \n? Should using just a basic .split() work?

Comment: I will have to try this out later. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @26hmkk No problem. Vote it up if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

How are you doing setText() in the textView.

Try this...

```
TextView view = your text view;
view.setSingleLine(false);
view.setText("first line\n"+"second line\n"+"third line");
```

Answer (score 1):

The text entered in an input field is used as an actual text. That means, when the user enters the `Hello \n World` and the code calls `getText().toString()`, what will actually be returned is: `Hello \\n World` that means, it's the actual slash symbol and not the `"carriage return"` symbol.

I don't believe android has any built-in API to give you the actual code typed by the user, that means, that you have to write that code yourself. If all you need is the `\n` as a carriage return it is simple:

```
getText().toString().replace("\\n", "\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

with

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

you get a String which results in a new line.
I would replace  \n by this expression.